# import .doc files to wordpress

Tags: wordpress, import

I am modifying a website on wordpress (codex) and I would like to import all the .doc files (about 200) from the old website and make them into posts on the wordpress website.
Any ideas how to do this bulk import or is the only way to copy and paste each one, which will take a long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There Is a way to do this - but as far as I know - it is not easy ..
I struggled with it one time - but could achieve it in the end .

The reason is that a WORD *.doc is a complicated format , and even simple Copy&Paste can make problems (as it actually copies also formatting)

You need to use the COM interface in php , turn the DOC to a TXT file or a string , and then create the post with `wp_insert_post( $my_post );`

so - opening the DOC . (you need to loop for bulk )

```
$filename="file.doc";
$TXTfilename = $filename . ".txt";
$word = new COM("word.application") or die("Unable to instantiate Word object");
$word->Documents->Open($filename);
$word->Documents[1]->SaveAs($TXTfilename ,2);//  '2' for txt format
$word->Documents[1]->Close(false);
$word->Quit();
$word->Release();
$word = NULL;
unset($word);
$my_doc_string = file_get_contents($TXTfilename); //write file
unlink($TXTfilename);
```

Then, either read a txt file , or if in the same function use the $my_doc_string directly.. :

```
$title_p = 'mypost no'.$i;
      $my_post = array(
      'post_title' => $title_p,
      'post_content' => $my_doc_string,
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'post_author' => 1 
      );
      $post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post );
     wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

NOTE : the COM interface , as far as I know , Is available only on the WINDOWS vesion of PHP , and you will also need to have MS WORD installed ...

some more reading for you :

http://php.net/manual/en/book.com.php

http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/php/ch15_03.htm

http://www.gsdesign.ro/blog/extracting-text-from-word-documents-in-php-with-com-objects/

**EDIT I -**

After reading your question again - if you have an OLD website - why do you need the DOC files ? you might be able to do that with an HTML PARSER (if the OLD website has the same content as the DOCs - but in HTML)

**EDIT II -** unbelievably - today I have stumbled into this plugin, it might be of some help although I did not tried it .

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/auto-poster/screenshots/

Comment: I tired the plugin but it didn't work. It could be because I am using the latest version of wordpress. If you have any other simple ideas that would be great. Otherwise what do you mean use the 'COM interface in php'? How do I do that? Where do I put the code?

Comment: once I've used the COM interface how do I import all the files to wordpress? Is this very complicated, would be quicker to copy and paste (350 doc files)?

Answer (score 1):

l downloaded a plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/mammoth-docx-converter/ that is able to import word documents into wordpress editor for publishing. Format mapping is not 100% but does the basic stuff. All i need to do now is to be able to populate metadata in association with that particular document (custom post) upon import using particular key words from the post Content to asynchronously populate the meta boxes. I am also trying to generate excerpts automatically from a particular paragraph (second paragraph) of the document.I read about wp all import plugin and find it quite close to what i want but cant really figure out how word documents can be imported at the same time automating the operations stated above. I was able to come up with an XML file from source using WRX specification leveraging exported Content from my Website and then uploading again for test purposes but that is not what i really want to achieve. Is there anyway wp all import plugin can be customized to do what i want?

I also find your php approach quite suitable and might be more appropriate for what i need it to do and my goal. Important for me is an automated import of the word document as a post keeping the formatting intact and and then asynchronously populating associated meta data automatically. Do you have any recommendations based on the above php COM Code?

Comment: This issue has been solved using the parser code above.